# Intel Fortran Composer XE code not running on AMD Ryzen Processor

Tags: compilation, fortran, intel, processor, amd-processor

I compile my scientific Fortran code using the following:

- Windows 10,
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010,
- Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2011.

(Newer versions are not available to me)

My new computer is using an AMD Ryzen 1700 processor. When I try to run compiled Release MKL or Release MKL - OpenMP I get the following error:

> Fatal Error: This program was not built to run on the processor in
> your system. The allowed processors are: Intel(R) processors with
> SSE4.2 and POPCNT instructions support.

Any ideas on how to make this work? I was really looking forward to using my 8 cores (at an affordable price) to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution. Right click your project -> Properties -> Select "All configurations". In configuration properties -> Fortran -> Code generation -> Intel processor-specific optimization -> Set this to "The processor performing the compilation (/QxHost)"